# Notificaciones no llegan a correo electrónico

Tags: laravel, notificaciones, mail, pusher

Estoy intentando mandar notificaciones de por correo electrónico y atraves de pusher.

Para pusher no tengo ningún problema. Este es el evento que emito cuando ocurre una acción.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewComment implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('events');
    }

    public function broadcastAs(){
        return 'new-comment';
    }
}
```

Este evento se trasmite bien.

Pero la notificación por correo electrónico nunca sale.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class AddComment extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Array $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->view('mail.notifications', ['message'=> $this->message]);
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Este es el orden en el que llamo a los metodos.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Request\CommentRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CreditController extends Controller
{

    public function addComment(CommentRequest $comment, User $user){
      Auth::user()->update(['comments'=> $comment]);
      event(new App\Events\NewComment($comment));
      $user->notify(new App\Notifications\AddComment ($comment));
    }

}
```

Obviamente al usuario lo inyecto desde el modelo por medio de la ruta.
Cuando hago un test esto no regresa ningún error de echo si crea la notificación en la base de datos pero nunca llega el correo con la notificación. Sin embargo al enviar el correo por separado con el la fachada **Mail**. Si lo envía.

Comment: Has revisado si en el log de errores de Laravel aparece algo?

Comment: Si pero esta vació el archivo. Pienso que tiene que ver algo con las configuraciones del canal de trasmisión por defecto. Dado que lo cambia pusher para hacer las notificaciones en tiempo real.

Comment: Descubri que solo desde tinker no funciona. Si hace el proceso normal. Si manda los correos.